# Selecting the whole data after joining in linq

Tags: c#, linq

When I need to join some tables using linq, and when those tables consist of a lot of fields, it takes a lot of work to get all the data that I need. For instance:

```
var result = from i in Person
             join y in Works
             on i.PID euqals y.PID
             join z in Groups
             on y.GID on z.GID
             select new {Name = i.Name, Work = y.work, WG = z.GroupName};
```

How can make the query return all the tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you need is simply this :

```
var Query = from x in Table_1
            join y in Table_2
            on x.id equals y.id
            where x.Country.Equals("X Country")
            select new {x,y};
```

Comment: After using this code, I could not enumerate in the query anymore.

Comment: @user3889986: This approach yields an object which contains your tables as distinct querables or enumerables . You have to select each one of them. Like for example `foreach(var i in Query) {Consol.WriteLine(i.x.Something)}`